# Group by not working with cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

consider the following query.
I have created a cursor for this query.
My Problem is group by not working properly in the cursor.but when i execute the query it gives perfect group by result.

when I iterate cursor using FETCH NEXT and WHILE loop it gives more than one group for the same point_id.

Can you help me to resolve this problem ???
thanks in advance..

```
select timestamp as 'TS',REPLACE(REPLACE(POINT_ID,'[','_'),']','_') AS POINT_ID,_VAL 
from TCF1_PULLCORD 
where timestamp between '11/01/2011 6:30:00 AM' and '12/01/2011 6:29:59 AM'
group by point_id,timestamp,_val


DECLARE MYCUR CURSOR 
FOR
    select timestamp as 'TS',REPLACE(REPLACE(POINT_ID,'[','_'),']','_') AS POINT_ID,_VAL 
    from TCF1_PULLCORD 
    where timestamp between '11/01/2011 6:30:00 AM' and '12/01/2011 6:29:59 AM'
    group by point_id,timestamp,_val
```

Comment: what do you mean "not working properly in the cursor"

Comment: IT GIVES ROWS FOR POINT_ID = 'DOOR_PROD_ST_1_' THEN GIVES FOR POINT_ID = 'DOOR_PROD_ST_10_' AND THEN FOR 'DOOR_PROD_ST_11_' AND AGAIN FOR 'DOOR_PROD_ST_1_'... I MEAN GROUPS ARE DIVIDED

Comment: @Dharmesh: please turn **OFF** your **CAPS LOCK KEY** - this is considering **YELLING** and it's **RUDE**

Comment: ohh I am really sorry if it is so.... marc

Comment: Can you show us how you're implementing your cursor? Table structures? Sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your database's way of saying "Please don't use a cursor on me."  :D

Just kidding, but in all seriousness you will find better performance iterating through a table variable than using a cursor.

```
DECLARE @timestamps TABLE( 
    TS DATETIME,
    POINT_ID VARCHAR(100),
    _VAL VARCHAR(100)
    )
DECLARE @currTimeStamp DATETIME 

INSERT INTO @timestamps 
select timestamp as 'TS',REPLACE(REPLACE(POINT_ID,'[','_'),']','_') AS POINT_ID,_VAL 
from TCF1_PULLCORD 
where timestamp between '11/01/2011 6:30:00 AM' and '12/01/2011 6:29:59 AM'
group by point_id,timestamp,_val


WHILE (SELECT COUNT(TS) FROM @timestamps > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @currTimeStamp = MIN(TS) FROM @timestamps
    --Do work here
    ...

    --Delete the timestamp we just worked on
    DELETE FROM @timestamps WHERE TS = @currTimeStamp
END
```

In addition, unless your SELECT is doing other things we can't see here, the GROUP BY should be unnecessary.  If you're not doing any aggregate functions (e.g. SUM, MAX, MIN) and you're really just trying to get the unique combinations, then SELECT DISTINCT is a more efficient way to get there.

In that case, your select would be:

```
select DISTINCT timestamp as 'TS',REPLACE(REPLACE(POINT_ID,'[','_'),']','_') AS POINT_ID,_VAL 
from TCF1_PULLCORD 
where timestamp between '11/01/2011 6:30:00 AM' and '12/01/2011 6:29:59 AM'
```

Comment: dear Jonathan. You have taught me a nice approach but its taking too much(more than 5 mins) of time in processing 44021 rows. when I display @timestamps table with select statement it gave me perfect result["INSERT INTO @timestamps"]. so your suggestion may work perfectly for small results(1000-2000) rows

Comment: it became faster when i use EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @timestamps). Thank you very much Jonathan

Comment: Yes, EXISTS can be faster in some cases. Adding a PRIMARY KEY to @timestamps may also improve performance in many cases. Optimization of answers is always a guess unless you have the actual data in hand.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you, but it is at least more accurate.

```
DECLARE MYCUR CURSOR 
FOR
    select  timestamp as 'TS'
            ,REPLACE(REPLACE(POINT_ID,'[','_'),']','_') AS POINT_ID
            ,_VAL 
    from    TCF1_PULLCORD 
    where   timestamp between '11/01/2011 6:30:00 AM' and '12/01/2011 6:29:59 AM'
    group by 
            REPLACE(REPLACE(POINT_ID,'[','_'),']','_')
            ,timestamp
            ,_val
```